# How to manipulate a char data type in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax, char

I have a table with customer information. CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, State, City, PostalCode. The postal code is a char data type. In the oracle devgym its asking me to subtract 1 from the PostalCode for all customers with a CustomerID between 100 and 200. I've tried doing something like

```
Update Customer
Set PostalCode = PostalCode - 1
Where CustomerID BETWEEN '100' AND '200'
```

But I believe since PostalCode is of char data type that I need to be looking for another solution. I can not find nothing online that gives me a clear answer to subtracting 1 from char datatype or maybe I'm asking the wrong questions.

Comment: Oracle supports implicit type conversions. Did you try any code? What the error you've got?

Comment: UPDATE Customer
 SET PostalCode = PostalCode - 1
WHERE CustomerId BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerId BETWEEN 100 AND 200;

Comment: If you absolutely sure that `PostalCode` is numeric (there's no any other symbols except spaces before/after the number), this will work and return a number (e.g. `'001234'` will return `1233`). If this is not your case (for example, you may also have other symbols) or you get the output you do not want/expect, then please provide some clarity in the question: what is wrong with the result, provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Which quiz in Oracle Dev Gym is this related to?

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this issue too.

1- If Customer_id is numeric, then you should try this;

```
Update Customer
Set PostalCode = to_number(PostalCode) - 1
Where CustomerID BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
```

2- and if Customer_id  is char try this:

```
Update Customer
Set PostalCode = to_number(PostalCode) - 1
Where to_number(CustomerID) BETWEEN 100 AND 200;
```

3- but if the table is heavy then I propose using a combination of truncate and insert instead of update because update command is too slowly.